# i want to display return data to convert json

Tags: php, json, laravel-5

these my table database in the model sub_bidang

```
id  id_bidang       name    
1      1            Backend Developer   
2      1            Frontend Developer  
3      2            Senior Marketing
```

i want to display all the name in the array nama sub bidang by field id bidang

```
$data = Posting::find($id);

    foreach ($data->sub_bidang as $value) {

        $data = [

            'id posting job' => $data->id_posting_job,
            'id kategori' => $data->id_kategori,
            'nama kategori' => $data->kategori_posting['nama'],
            'id bidang' => $data->id_bidang,
            'nama bidang' => $data->bidang['nama'],
            'nama sub bidang' => [
                'bidang' => $value->nama
            ]  
        ]; 

        return response()->json($data);
    }
```

but doesnt work, just display backend developer in the array nama sub bidang. like this

```
{
  "id posting job": 1,
  "id kategori": 1,
  "nama kategori": "Part Time",
  "id bidang": 1,
  "nama bidang": "IT",
  "nama sub bidang": {
    "bidang": "Backend Developer"
  }
}
```

there should be display backend developer and frontend developer, 
what the problem?

Comment: Right syntax here : `return response->json([ "data" => "Return any value or define array here ]);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here try following

```
.......................
.......................
$result_data = array();
foreach ($data->sub_bidang as $value) {

    $result_data[] = array(
        'id posting job' => $data->id_posting_job,
        'id kategori' => $data->id_kategori,
        'nama kategori' => $data->kategori_posting['nama'],
        'id bidang' => $data->id_bidang,
        'nama bidang' => $data->bidang['nama'],
        'nama sub bidang' => array(
            'bidang' => $value->nama
        )
    ); 


} 
return response()->json($result_data);
```

**Note:** The `$result_date`  be php array so the `response()->json()` method will automatically generate `JSON`.